# Прогресс бар не работает и не отображается. Что с ним не так?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/full_wifi" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="297dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ssid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Setting connection..."
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

```
public class WifiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

static final String NO_INTERNET = "No internet";
static final String SSID = "SSID";
static final String LEVEL = "level";
static final String CAPABILITIES = "capabilities";
static final String STATUS = "status";
static final String SECURITY = "security";
static final String SECURITY_OPEN = "open";
static final String PENDING = "pending...";
static final String DEBUG = "debug";
static final String[] SECURITY_TYPE_LIST = {"WPA", "WPA", "WEP", "IEEE8021X"};
static final String STATE_CHECKING = "connection testing...";

WifiAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wifiList) {
    super(context, 0 , wifiList);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    HashMap<String, String> wifiData = getItem(position);
    if (wifiData == null){
        wifiData = new HashMap<>();
    }
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wifiitem, parent, false);
    }
    TextView ssid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ssid);
    TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

    ImageView complete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strength);

    String ssid_value = wifiData.get(WifiAdapter.SSID);
    ssid.setText(ssid_value  != null ? ssid_value : "Empty");
    status.setText(wifiData.get(WifiAdapter.STATUS));

    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    //TODO fix progressbar  - it does'n work
    //TODO - we able use show real progress from Connection Test task
    if (WifiAdapter.STATUS.equals(WifiAdapter.STATE_CHECKING)) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (wifiData.get(WifiAdapter.SECURITY).equals(WifiAdapter.SECURITY_OPEN)){
        int level = Integer.parseInt(wifiData.get(WifiAdapter.LEVEL));
        if (level <= -70) {
            complete.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_wifi);
        } else if (level <= -60) {
            complete.setImageResource(R.drawable.quat_wifi);
        } else if (level <= -40) {
            complete.setImageResource(R.drawable.half_wifi);
        } else if (level <= -30) {
            complete.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_wifi);
        }
    } else{
        complete.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock);
    }

    return convertView;

}

}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на русскоязычный SO, переведите свой вопрос согласно правилам сайта. Вопросы на других языках являются оффтоп.

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомившись с вашей разметкой я кажется понял в чем у вас может быть проблема, но я могу ошибаться. У вас есть макет LinearLayout и чтобы виджет progressBar находился на экране его нужно разместить внутри вашего layout а он у вас находится за его пределами. Закрывающая скобка вашего главного layout либо не отображена в вопросе либо ее нету. Я бы вас посоветовал пересмотреть вашу разметку и удостовериться в том что ваши виджеты находятся на заранее определенных местах. Вот есть [первая](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar.php) и [вторая](https://www.journaldev.com/9629/android-progressbar-example) ссылка по вашему вопросу. Может поможет разобраться. Проблема номер 2 - он не работает. Конечно он не работает, потому что вы его даже не видите, и как следствие не можете узнать работает он или нет. Ваша приоритетная задача проверить разметку и сделать ваш progressbar видимым и дальше уже станет понятно работает он или нет. И как вариант вам нужно в вашей разметке указать параметр для вашего бара - `android:visibility="gone"` чтобы дальше управлять его показом или скрытием в процессе работы программы. Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог. Удачи :)

P.S. Если все-таки не сможете решить свою проблему, то приложите к вопросу актуальную разметку и постарайтесь дать больше деталей по вашей проблеме, и тогда вероятность того что вам здесь помогут резко возрастет.

Comment: LinearLayout самого верхнего уровня закрыт.     android:visibility="visible" -  то есть его должно быть видно. Но кагда запускаю эмулятор то на месте прогрес бара пустое место.

Comment: а попробуйте забрать visibility вообще, изначально он должен появится а дальше вам будет проще им управлять

Comment: `    if (WifiAdapter.STATUS.equals(WifiAdapter.STATE_CHECKING)) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }`

Comment: понял что проблема именно здесь

Comment: но почему не понимаю

Comment: попробуйте поменять местами, может появится